# Convert letter based on given information?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a csv file looks like below, and I would like to convert the letter (A or B) starting from 4th column based on the representative information (2th and 3rd column). But number '0' will be remained as '0'.

```
Name, A_Rep,B_Rep,id_1,id_1,id_2,id_2,...  # header line 
rs1,      G,    T,   A,   A,   A,   B,...
rs2,      A,    G,   0,   0,   A,   B,...
```

After converting then I can see...

```
Name, A_Rep,B_Rep,id_1,id_1,id_2,id_2,...   
 rs1,     G,    T,   G,   G,   G,   T,... 
 rs2,     A,    G,   0,   0,   A,   G,...
```

Below is the code finished, but still showing the message in
`A_Rep = line[1] IndexError: list index out of range`.

```
    import csv

    input = 'input.csv'

    with open('output.csv', 'w') as output:
        data = csv.reader(input, delimiter=',')
        for line in data:
            if line[0].startswith('Name'): # Retrieve the header line
                output.write("{}\n".format(','.join(line)))
            else:
                stuff = [] 
                Name = line[0]
                A_Rep = line[1]     ##IndexError: list index out of range
                B_Rep = line[2]     ##IndexError: list index out of range 
                for samplefield in line[3:]:
                    if samplefield == 'A':
                        stuff.append(A_Rep)
                    elif samplefield == 'B':
                        stuff.append(B_Rep)
                    elif samplefield == '0':
                        stuff.append('0')
                    else:
                        sys.exit('Check: {}'.format(','.join(line)))
                output.write("{},{},{},{}\n".format(Name, A_Rep, B_Rep, ','.join(stuff)))
```

Does anyone know how to solve it, or even an efficient way to make the same goal?

Comment: You can not use `-` in variable names. this is equal semantically to subtraction.

Comment: That is odd. You *should* get "SyntaxError: can't assign to operator" on that line. Are you sure this is an exact copy-paste of your program?

Comment: are you sure you are using python 2.7 ? whats the output for: `import sys print (sys.version)`

Comment: '-' revised, yes I edited a bit while posting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using file handler properly, i would implement above logic like this:

```
with open("input.csv") as inputFile, open("output.csv", 'w') as outputFile:
    outCsv = csv.writer(outputFile, delimiter=',')
    inCsv = csv.reader(inputFile, delimiter=',')

    header = next(inCsv)
    outCsv.writerow(header)

    for line in inCsv:
        newLine = line[0:3]
        for value in line[3:]:
            value = value.strip()
            code = {
                'A': line[1],
                'B': line[2],
                '0': value
            }
            newLine.append(code[value])

        outCsv.writerow(newLine)
```